# Spacebar No Longer Scrolling Down in Outlook Messages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

I was pressing the spacebar repeatedly in an Outlook message window.  A dialog opened and my scrollbar press probably registered as OK to the dialog.  Now the spacebar no longer scrolls down in message windows.  The option "Single key reading using space bar" is checked and does work in the Reading Pane, but doesn't affect the Messages that are opened in their own window.  I've looked in the Accessibility options for something that changed, but can't find anything that helps.